# Further understanding "Completing the square" technique. Why is $x^2 -2x +2 = (x-1)^2 - 1^2 + 2 = (x-1)^2 +1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Why is $x^2 -2x +2 = (x-1)^2 - 1^2 + 2 = (x-1)^2 +1$?

I was reviewing some elementary algebra and inequalities and I came across this solution. Why is it not simply $(x-1)^2$?

Comment: $(x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1$

Comment: There is definitely an error since $(x-1)^2+3 \neq (x-1)^2 +1$.

Comment: If you can, share the original source where you found this expression.  Either it was an error on the original author's part, or you misread it.  As it stands, it is most certainly incorrect as written.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144) After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: You should also include more context. Where are you getting $x^2-2x+1=(x-1)^2+1^2+2=(x-1)^2+1$? It's not clear what you're asking if you don't explain how you came to these equalities, of which none are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone! A few considerations: There was a typo in my original title. 
Nonetheless, thank you [Clive Newstead](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/19542/clive-newstead) for understanding it and still being able to provide a great answer considering the "potential typos". That let me to an answer and understanding.

I investigated further and I remembered that this is a "completing the square" problem. The typos didn't let me realise this and made me confused.

But for clarity, this is how I understood the problem:

The standard form of $(x-1)^2$ is $x^2 - 2ax + a^2$

I was able to get from my original equation $x^2 -2x + 2$ to $(x-1)^2$ easily.

However, comparing to the standard form, I need $a = 1$ so that  $x^2 - 2ax$ = $x^2 - 2x$.

Hence,

$(x-a)^2 = x^2 - 2ax + a^2$

and given $a = 1$

we have
$(x-1)^2 = x^2 - 2(1)x + 1^2$

meaning that I can also write the first two elements of my original equation as
$(x-1)^2 -1^2 = x^2 - 2x$

Hence, the final solution will be

$(x-1)^2 - 1^2 + 2 = (x-1)^2 + 1$

Thanks everyone for the patience. After more than 10 years since I was done with high school I am really glad to get back to work. My goal is to be proficient in Multivariate Calculus in a few months. I am dedicating 3 to 4h a day to study and review EVERYTHING!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the same: $$(x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1$$ and $$(x-1)^2+1^2+2=x^2-2x+1+1+2$$
$$(x-1)^2+1=x^2-2x+1+1$$

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that it is equal to $(x-1)^2$.

The pattern of this makes it look like it has to do with completing the square, but there are two typos: the $+$ before the $1^2$ should be a $-$, and either (a) the $2$ should be a $1$, or (b) the $+1$ term in the polynomial should be a $+2$.

In general, we have
$$x^2+2ax+b = (x+a)^2 - a^2 + b$$

In this case, depending on whether it's typo (a) or typo (b), what we *should* have is either
$$x^2-2x+1 = (x-1)^2 - 1 + 1 = (x-1)^2$$
or
$$x^2-2x+2 = (x-1)^2 - 1 + 2 = (x-1)^2 + 1$$

Comment: Ok - So there's definitely two typos. You're correct, there's an errata: the problem should be $x^2 -2x + 2$ and the solution should be $(x-1)^2 -1^2 + 2$.

Comment: Where can I get more information regarding $(x+a)^2 - a^2 + b$? It is still not very clear to me why that is. Even still shouldn't the final solution be $(x-1)^2$ ?

Comment: Never mind. Just realised what that is (: 
Thanks for the help.